# Hoe do you update a Control property from another Control's action

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am trying to on/off a toggle button on a button `OnSelect` Action in PowerApps.

Its not working. I have tired code as follows but it did not work:

```
UpdateContext({DataCardValue8:DataCardValue8.Value=false}) //or
UpdateContext({DataCardValue8.Value=false}) //or
UpdateContext({DataCardValue8.Value:false})
//toggle button control Id is DataCardValue8
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should set the toggle's Default property to a variable, say MyToggleValue

Then you should set the button's OnSelect to:
`UpdateContext({MyToggleValue:!MyToggleValue})`